# OpenDDS build failure

Tags: ace, tao, data-distribution-service

I'm trying to build OpenDDS 3.4.1 with ACE+TAO-6.2.3. While following the DDS/INSTALL docs, option B, I'm running into the following build errors.

Here is directory location ...

```
/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/
|- ACE+TAO-6.2.3.tar
|- ACE_wrappers
|- DDS
`- OpenDDS-3.4.1.tar
```

Environment variables ...

```
ACE_ROOT=/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/ACE_wrappers
TAO_ROOT=/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/ACE_wrappers/TAO
DDS_ROOT=/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/DDS
MPC_ROOT=/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/ACE_wrappers/MPC
CIAO_ROOT=/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/ACE_wrappers/CIAO
```

And this is the build error I'm trying to get past.

```
g++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -W -Wpointer-arith -pipe -D_GNU_SOURCE  -DNDEBUG  -I/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/ACE_wrappers -I/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/DDS -DACE_NDEBUG -D__ACE_INLINE__ -I/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/ACE_wrappers -I/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/ACE_wrappers/TAO -I../../../.. -DOPENDDS_TCP_BUILD_DLL  -c -fPIC -o .shobj/TcpReceiveStrategy.o TcpReceiveStrategy.cpp
In file included from TcpReceiveStrategy.h:14:0,
             from TcpReceiveStrategy.cpp:10:
/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/DDS/dds/DCPS/transport/framework/TransportReceiveStrategy_T.h:61:33: error: 'ACE_INET_Addr' has not been declared
/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/DDS/dds/DCPS/transport/framework/TransportReceiveStrategy_T.h:72:37: error: 'ACE_INET_Addr' does not name a type
/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/DDS/dds/DCPS/transport/framework/TransportReceiveStrategy_T.h:72:52: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'remote_address' with no type [-fpermissive]
make[1]: *** [.shobj/TcpReceiveStrategy.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ender/OpenDDS-3.4.1/DDS/dds/DCPS/transport/tcp'
make: *** [OpenDDS_Tcp] Error 2
```

I've built this before and it worked, but can't see why I'm having troubles this time around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been some refactoring in ACE which causes OpenDDS 3.4.1 not to compile with ACE/TAO x.2.3. You have to manually add an include of ace/INET_Addr.h to dds/DCPS/transport/framework/TransportReceiveStrategy_T.h as done in commit [5998](https://svn.dre.vanderbilt.edu/viewvc/DDS/trunk/dds/DCPS/transport/framework/TransportReceiveStrategy_T.h?r1=5804&r2=5998) of OpenDDS.